# Optimizing find command

Tags: linux, performance, unix, find

I have about a million files for which I need to get the filename, size, and date modified.

Is there any improvement that can be done, performance-wise, on the following command to get this information?

```
find ./ -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

Note: I can exclude files such as ".file", ".trash/", and any folders themselves (i.e., I only need the file information).

**Update:**

Here are the results:

```
$ time (find . -ls)
real    0m5.947s
user    0m0.393s
sys     0m0.682s

$ time (ls -lhR)
real    0m14.208s
user    0m0.978s
sys     0m2.510s

$ time (find ./ -exec ls -lh {} \;)
way too long
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, quite a bit. Faster alternatives include:

- Running the `ls` command in larger batches than one file at a time:

  ```
  find . -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lh
  ```
- Having `find` do the file listing instead of a separate `ls` command:

  ```
  find . -ls
  ```
- Skipping `find` altogether and having `ls` run recursively:

  ```
  ls -lhR
  ```

Comment: Thank you, which of the above do you think would be optimal?

Comment: Either of the last two will perform very well. Which one you'll want will depend on the output format you need.

Comment: Great, thank you. Is there any difference in doing `find . -ls` and `find ./ -ls` ?

Comment: `find ./` will end up spitting out silly-looking paths like `.//filename`. Other than that, it's the same.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the `\;` to `+` will tell `find` to stuff as many files into the command line as it can, reducing the number of invocations of `ls`, which should significantly improve performance.

Comment: wow, I was running this code to search files older than 60 days with \; option and it was taking 5-6 hours and then I read your answer and used + , now the command executed within a minute, thank you so much